# Does wordplay boiled soy/soiled boy have a name?

Tags: puns

In Polish, there is a relatively established literary pastime of finding two pairs of words having forms *a1a2 b1b2* and *b1a2 a1b2*, where both pairs are realistic phrases (i.e., they have a sensible meaning and are not unrelated), and the second pair has a dirty meaning.

They are usually *adjective noun* or *noun verb*.

Does this wordplay have a name in English?

Comment: Here's a similar one not mentioned in the dup: "I like a well-boiled icicle".

Comment: Swapping one consonant (or cluster) for another is called **Metonymy**. Saying "ax" instead of "ask" is contact metonymy (/k/ and /s/ remain in contact), whereas "boiled soy" instead of "soiled boy" is distance metonymy (they're not in contact). It doesn't matter what kind of words or part of speech it is -- it's all sound, no grammar. There are specific types of metonymy like Spoonerisms, too.

Comment: Metonymy is swapping one consonant for another? I thought it meant a figure of speech where one term is substituted for another closely associated to it.  Like Hollywood for the American movie industry.

Comment: I don’t think this question duplicates the earlier one. Here OP is not asking about errors but (intentional) wordplay. I suspect @Turin has in mind things more like, “I’d rather have a bottle in front o’ me than a frontal lobotomy.”   There’s also a class of riddles/jokes for which it is **assumed** that the listener will **know** to perform just this type of phoneme-swapping to create or complete the punch line (I apologize but the only example coming to mind is obscene, so I don’t include it here.)

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum One that's fit for punchlines without being obscene is making sure to check the (*nooks*, *crannies*) ↔ (*crooks*, *nannies*).

Comment: And one that’s not too off color would be, “**Q.** What’s the difference between *boulangers* and a happy newlywed couple? **A.** The *boulangers* bake the bread, while the newlyweds…”

Comment: @tchrist - also a movie written by Evan Hunter (Ed McBain)